# Как центрировать инфо окно?

Tags: android, google-maps

У меня есть **InfoWindow** для маркеров.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
public class MyCustomAdapterForItems implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {
    private final View myContentsView;
    MyCustomAdapterForItems() {
        myContentsView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_item_info_window, null);
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {

        TextView tvName = ((TextView) myContentsView.findViewById(R.id.txtName));
        TextView tvSity = ((TextView) myContentsView.findViewById(R.id.txtSity));
        TextView tvAdress = ((TextView) myContentsView.findViewById(R.id.txtAdress));
        TextView tvPhone = ((TextView) myContentsView.findViewById(R.id.txtPhone));
        TextView tvBegin = ((TextView) myContentsView.findViewById(R.id.txtBegin));
        TextView tvEnding = ((TextView) myContentsView.findViewById(R.id.txtEnding));

        tvName.setText(clickedClusterItem.getName());
        tvSity.setText(clickedClusterItem.getSity());
        tvAdress.setText(clickedClusterItem.getAdress());
        tvPhone.setText(clickedClusterItem.getPhone());
        tvBegin.setText(clickedClusterItem.getBegin());
        tvEnding.setText(clickedClusterItem.getEnding());

        return myContentsView;
    }
```

Часть **InfoWindow** скрывается за экраном. Вёрстка отступов в `R.layout.my_item_info_window` не помогает. Что необходимо, чтоб окно было ниже `ActionBar`?

Comment: Передвинте пини немного ниже. не по центру. А 30% от нижнего края. Вот и инфоюокс будет полным виден

Comment: Пини это маркеры?

Comment: да, маркеры. При клике можно их опускать

Comment: Не подскажите как?

Answer (score 3):

обично это делается так

```
// получаем текуший latitude 
double latitude = location.getLatitude();

// получаем текуший longitude 
double longitude = location.getLongitude();

// Создает точку для карты 
LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
now = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng)));

// Переводим камеру на указанную точку
googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

// Показываем нужным нам Zoom
googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
```

А вам нужно уменшить `longitude` в зависимости `Zoom`а на несколько метров. Что бы камера карты центрировала не маркер а точку ниже координат маркера

Comment: Так если я буду уменьшать широту и долготу, это изменит координаты маркера.  Это важно, потому что дальше будет построение маршрута к маркерам.

Comment: или это только для камеры, а у самих маркеров будут нужные координаты?

Comment: координаты маркеров остаются, так же как и сейчас, только для камеры нужно будет координату из выбранного маркера создать. Тоесть клиент выберает маркер, программа вычесляет точку для камеры из координат выбранного маркера и движет камеру. А маркеров не трогает